# Looking for numerical integration methods that only depends on endpoints.

Tags: integration, reference-request, numerical-methods, quadrature

I am looking for references for numerical methods of integration that only use information about the endpoints of integration (like the trapezoidal rule). I have a very unusual problem where I have a continuous function which I can evaluate (and find the derivatives) at the endpoints of integration but not in-between endpoints. Any references to advanced numerical integration methods in one dimension that uses information at the end points would be appreciated.

*Notes*

- If you need clarification don't hesitate to ask.
- The integral that I am trying to evaluate has been divided into a set of integrals which are much simpler. The endpoints of this simple integrals cannot be changed and the endpoints are not evenly spaced.
- The trapezoidal rule is sufficient for my purposes, but having a more accurate method would be perferable.

Comment: I can't think of a two-point-per-subinterval method that is better than the trapezoidal rule, though I suppose potentially you could use the derivative data. But doing so has a good chance of doing weird things, similar to the usual problems with high order interpolation.

Comment: I would recommend cubic splines. You can fit cubic splines to the points on the interval boundaries, and then integrate the cubics exactly. This is not far from Simpson's rule.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_interpolation

Comment: @Ian I couldn't think of a better method either. But I figured I should ask.